# how to pass credentials with angular-http-auth?

Tags: javascript, authentication, angularjs

Inside my app, authentication is working with [angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth)

when user fill the username / password form and submit, it targets the `login()` function from the controller :

```
$scope.login = function() {
    var credentials = Base64.encode($scope.username + ':' + $scope.password);
    $http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + credentials;

    User.login(                           // reference to the $resource service
        function() {                      // success callback
            authService.loginConfirmed(); // method of angular-http-auth
        }
    );

}
```

User is a service created with $resource

```
factory('User', function($resource){
    return $resource('url/to/json', 
        {}, 
        {   'login': { method: 'GET', isArray:true }
        });
})
```

and base64 is an encrypting service coming from [here](http://wemadeyoulook.at/en/blog/implementing-basic-http-authentication-http-requests-angular/)

This is working like this, but is there a way to pass the credentials through angular-http-auth instead of setting default headers through $http ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with doing this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + credentials;
```

is that you're now setting the "credentials" for all $http requests that are made.  If you don't want to do that, and you want to pass the "credentials" with each $resource call directly, you can, which is what it looks like you're starting to do there.

```
return $resource('url/to/json', 
    {}, 
    {   'login': {
             method: 'GET',
             headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + credentials }
         }
    });
```

I didn't try this very example, but I have I similar code where the method is a POST so I call save() on the result of $resource before returning it, and the 'login' key is 'save'

But since you're doing a GET, with a custom "login" method, this should work.

Comment: how to call it? :|