# how to set custom headers with a $resource action?

Tags: angularjs

with $http, we can do this:

```
var config = { headers: { 'something': 'anything' } };          
$http.get('url/to/json', config)
    .success(function() {
        // do something…
    })
```

i would like to do the same with a $resource reference (not working):

```
var config = { headers: { 'something': 'anything' } };
MyResource.get( 
    config,
    function() { // success
        // do something…
    }
);
```

with the corresponding service declared like this :

```
.factory('MyResource', function($resource){
    return $resource('url/to/json');
})
```

it's not working : the config object goes to the url and not in the http headers.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

`headers` for `$resource` is available since AngularJS 1.1.1. Make sure you have correct version used.

The format is

```
$resource('url/to/json', {}, {headers: { 'something': 'anything' }});
```

[edit by zuma]
The above doesn't seem right.   The third parameter to $resource should be a different.  This seems more correct to me:

```
$resource('url/to/json', {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'something': 'anything' }
    }
});
```

Comment: i would like to set the custom headers when using a `MyResource.action()` from the controller, not from the service (like in my example).

Comment: The third parameter should be an object where the key is the method, such as get, post, or a custom method, and it's value should be an object that has a 'method' key with the value of the http method, such as GET, and the headers object.

Comment: What about if you need to use Base64 encoding? I can't seem to get headers: { 'Authorization': "Basic " + Base64.encode("something" + ":" + "anything")} working.

Comment: @zsong but anyone can see these headers in the source code? How would I send an API key without the general public getting hold of it and abusing my account with a REST service?

Comment: @twigg Old comment, but this had me confused too, so for posterity: it's critical that the connection between client and server is encrypted. That's how to protect the header information

Comment: This would not help you with dynamic headers.

Answer (score 19):

The `headers` object inside a resource action supports both `static` values for its fields, but also `dynamic` values returned from a function.

```
$resource('url/to/json', {}, {
        get: {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 
               'header_static': 'static_value',
               'header_dynamic': dynamicHeaderVal
            }
        }
});

function dynamicHeaderVal(requestConfig){
     // this function will be called every time the "get" action gets called
     // the result will be used as value for the header item
     // if it doesn't return a value, the key will not be present in the header
}
```

Comment: Yes, I need a dynamic header!

Comment: Shout out for the amazing answer!

Answer (score 15):

Demo Code

```
angular.module('Test',['ngResource'])
 .controller('corsCtrl', function ($scope, $http, MyResource) {

  $http.defaults.headers.common['test']= 'team'; //Using $http we can set header also
  MyResource.get();
})
.factory('MyResource', function($resource) {   //Services
  return $resource('url/to/json');
})
```

[JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BTcdp/)

```
see in Request Header
```

Comment: actually, that's what i am doing already, but i was wondering if it was possible to avoid the `$http.defaults.headers…` line and use something specific to $resource. btw, do you know the difference between `$http.defaults.headers.common` and `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common` ?

Comment: $httpProvider need to set in config e.g app.config(function(httpProvider) { ...})

Comment: i asked another related question with this syntax : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18920255/how-to-pass-credentials-with-angular-http-auth

Comment: otherwise how will you add header ?

Comment: i was expeting a solution with $resource only: pass the headers as a parameter or something like this. but apparently it's not possible

Comment: Might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750366/with-angularjs-i-dont-want-to-set-the-global-http-defaults-headers-common-ca

Answer (score 2):

To use "Content-Type" header you may need to specify a data body at least for versions around 1.4.7+ due to $http deleting headers without a data body that are === 'content-type'. See #10255 in [1.4.7/angular.js](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js)

I just set "data: false" to spoof it, without specifying a data body:

```
$resource('url/to/json', {}, {
    get: {
        method: 'GET',
        data: false,
        headers: { 'something': 'anything' }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set dynamic one-off headers by accessing the config API object in the resource

Demo Code

```
angular.
.factory('Resource',['$resource',function($resource){return $resource(baseUrl+'/resource/:id', {id: '@_id'}, {
update    : {
  method  : 'POST',
  url     : baseUrl+'/resource/:id',
  headers : {
    'custom-header': function(config) {
      // access variable via config.data
      return config.data.customHeaderValue;
    }
  },
  transformRequest: function(data) {
    // you can delete the variable if you don't want it sent to the backend
    delete data['customHeaderValue'];
    // transform payload before sending
    return JSON.stringify(data);
  }
} 
});
}]);
```

To execute

```
Resource.update({},{
  customHeaderValue: setCustomHeaderValue
},
function (response) {
  // do something ...
},function(error){
  // process error
});
```