# Setting authentication headers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am just starting to learn about frameworks, I decided to start out with AngularJS. I am creating a resource to connect to a RESTful API and I need to set a custom header. I've tried looking around but I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
function KnackCtrl($scope, $resource) {
$scope.knack = $resource('https://api.knackhq.com/v1/objects/object_2/records'), {}, {headers: {'X-Knack-REST-API-Key': 'knack'}};
$scope.knack.get();
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set custom headers with a $resource action?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924217/how-to-set-custom-headers-with-a-resource-action)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, I managed to set the custom headers in my .config as follows:

```
var myApp =
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])
 .config(['$httpProvider',
            function ($httpProvider) {  
                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['header'] = 'value'
                $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['header'] = 'value'
}]);
```