# ngResource add header to request not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to send token in the header but it is not working, what is the way of sending token in the header? Or what is the problem in my code?

```
 return $q(function(resolve , reject){
    var token = StorageService.getToken();
    if(!token)
        console.log('no token')
    var resource = $resource(usersAPI.profile,null,
        {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                header: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
                }
            }
        })

    var profile = resource.query(function(result){
        console.log(result)
    },function(err){
        console.log('error',err)
    })
    resolve(profile)

})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924217/how-to-set-custom-headers-with-a-resource-action

Comment: I fixed, and the problem is in header object, should headers "Misspelled".