# Is there any way to set the custom header when making a API call?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angular-resource

I want to add custom header at the time of API call. I am actually calling a function from controller and inside that function the $resource object is going to be set as follows:

```
// Generate the $resource object based on the stored API object
                    var resourceObject = $resource(apiObject.url, apiObject.paramDefaults, apiObject.actions, apiObject.options);

                    // Make the call...
                    resourceObject[method](params,

                        // Success
                        function (response)
                        {
                            deferred.resolve(response);

                            // Emit an event
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('msApi::resolveSuccess');
                        },

                        // Error
                        function (response)
                        {
                            deferred.reject(response);

                            // Emit an event
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('msApi::resolveError');
                        }
                    );
```

**How to add custom header inside this ?**

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924217/how-to-set-custom-headers-with-a-resource-action

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the headers in as your options object. This should work for you.

```
var resourceObject = $resource(apiObject.url, apiObject.paramDefaults, apiObject.actions, {headers: { 'something': 'anything' }});
```

Or if you want to keep your original syntax.

```
apiObject.options = {headers: { 'something': 'anything' }}

var resourceObject = $resource(apiObject.url, apiObject.paramDefaults, apiObject.actions, apiObject.options );
```