# cors-anywhere.herokuapp status of 400 (Header required)

Tags: angularjs, api, http, openweathermap, mixed-content

I'm new to AngularJS, and am building an app on Udemy using the openweathermap api. The API is http, so heroku is blocking the mixed content.

I read that I can use cors-anywhere.herokuapp to get around this issue, but then I receive this error:
"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Header required)"

Here's the code in my controller: 
$scope.weatherAPI = $resource("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=4180439&appid=56acd9fb4a4f6138a4dd1055a7fde1fd", {callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});

My question is how do I add this header in AngularJS using $resource?

Thanks for your help!

It looks like for the "cors anywhere" addition to the api call to work I need to add a request header? I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

My app:
https://weather-app-gurliaccio.herokuapp.com/#/

I guess my question is really how do I add http request header in AngularJS?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924217/how-to-set-custom-headers-with-a-resource-action/18924312#18924312

Comment: Thanks! sideshowbarker